# A bilinear estimate in Lp space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $\varphi(D)$ be a Fourier multiplier with symbol $\varphi(\xi) = \xi/(1+|\xi|^2)$. It's easy to prove that
\begin{equation}
\|\varphi(D)u^2\|_{H^s(R)}\lesssim \|u\|^2_{H^s(R)}      \quad  (*)
\end{equation}
for any $s\geq 0$. Moreover, $(*)$ fails for $s<0$. Indeed, let 
$$
u(x)=\frac{8}{x}\cos\frac{2N+\gamma}{2}x\sin\frac{\gamma}{2} x
$$
such that the Fourier transform of $u$
$$
\widehat{u}(\xi)=1_{[-N-\gamma,-N]}+1_{[N,N+\gamma]}.
$$
Now an elementary calculation yields that $(*)$ becomes
$$
\gamma^{\frac{3}{2}}\lesssim N^{2s}\gamma.
$$
Since $s<0$, we set $\gamma=N^{-\varepsilon}(\varepsilon$ depends on $s$) and let $N\rightarrow \infty$ leads to a contradiction.

The above argument gives us a full picture of $(*)$ in scales of $H^s$ space. Now I'm interested in the $L^p$ version of $(*)$.
It's easy to show that
\begin{equation}
\|\varphi(D)u^2\|_{L^p(R)}\lesssim \|u\|^2_{L^p(R)} \quad (**)
\end{equation}
for any $p\geq 2$. Note that $p=2$ coincides the borderline case $s=0$. So my question is, does $(**)$ holds for $p<2$? If it does not, what kind of counterexamples may work. Observe that the above example fails in this problem.

Comment: Let $u^2$ be the Dirac mass (yeah, impossible as written, but quite possible as an approximation). Then $u_n\to 0$ in $L^p$ with $p<2$ but whatever non-zero operator you apply to $u_n^2$, the result tends to something nontrivial.